# Creating a WordPress plugin that uses the HTTP API to connect to external API

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a plugin that connects to an API to fetch a list of products and display information about each of them. I understand that I will most likely use the HTTP API provided from WordPress, but I found the documentation very vague and I don't know where to start. I searched for other materials on this matter but I couldn't find anything related to WP plugins that get data from external APIs.

Does anyone know any good resource about this or have any suggestion about what steps I should follow?

EDIT: What I am looking for is maybe an example of how the WP HTTP API is used in a WP Plugin. I have searched everywhere but all I can find is the WP REST API  and that is something completely different from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This post on Sitepoint is a bit old, but still does a pretty good job at explaining the different parts of the HTTP API: https://www.sitepoint.com/the-wordpress-http-api/

Just be sure to look up the functions mentioned there to see if they changed in the past four years.

Comment: Thank you, that seems useful. It doesn't have any explanation how the HTTP API would be used inside a plugin though.